# Debugging pylons in Eclipse under Ubuntu

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, pylons

I am trying to get pylons to debug in Eclipse under Ubuntu.
Specifically. I am not sure what to use for the 'Main Module' on the Run configurations dialog.

([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147650/debug-pylons-application-through-eclipse) is a similar question on stackoverflow, but I think it applies to windows as I can't find paster-script.py on my system)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to fix this now.

In `Window>Preferences>Pydev>Interpreter-Python` remove the python interpreter and reload it (select `New`) after installing pylons.

In the Terminal cd into the projects directory. Then type `sudo python setup.py develop` 
Not sure what this does, but it does the trick (if any one wants to fill me in, please do)

In `Run>Open Debug Dialog` enter the location of paster in `Main Module`. For me this is `/usr/bin/paster` . Then in the `Arguments` tab in `Program arguments` enter `serve /locationOfYourProject/development.ini`

All set to go.
It took a lot of search for me to find out that it does not work if the arguments includes `--reload`

Answer (score 1):

I got it running basically almost the same way - although you do not have to do the setup.py develop step - it works fine without that.

What it does is that is sets global link to your project directory for a python package named after your project name.

Answer (score 1):

I do need this step "sudo python setup.py develop" to get it running.. otherwise it throw out some exceptions.

btw, the setup.py is the one in your created project.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried on Eclipse, but I bet the solution I have been using to debug Pylons apps in WingIDE will work here too.

1. Write the following two-liner (name it run_me.py or similarly) and save it in your project directory:

   from paste.script.serve import ServeCommand

   ServeCommand("serve").run(["development.ini"])
2. Set this file as main debug target (aka main module)
3. Enjoy.