# How to debug and setup break points with Aptana/Eclipse using Pyramid Framework?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, aptana, pydev, pyramid

I'm having trouble starting debug mode in Aptana using the Pyramid Framework.

The platform I'm using is Debian/Linux, running Python 3.

These are the commands I use to create and run a Pyramid project. ([source](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/project.html))

```
1. pcreate -s starter MyProject      //create project
2. python3.2 setup.py develop        //setup develop mode
3. pserve development.ini            //run application
```

When I run the 3rd step the terminal shows this and I able to open the browser and view the site.

```
Starting server in PID 15507.
serving on "http://0.0.0.0:6543"
```

How do I run the debugger and setup breakpoints so I can step through the code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to look into [the python debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). There is also [an example for debugging Pyramid applications](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/debugging.html). This might also help: [Debug Pylons application through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147650/debug-pylons-application-through-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

This is (or at least was) an issue with Waitress' (the local server running your webapp) interaction with Aptana/pydev/Eclipse.

For Python 2.7, the simple answer is to use paster instead as the local server, which is what I did successfully. Unfortunately Paster has not yet been ported to Python 3 yet, so out of luck there if Python 3 is a requirement.

This may now have been fixed though, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073858/cant-debug-a-pyramid-project-in-eclipse-pydev-with-waitress). Also has some more detailed instructions on how to get paster working, although for 3.x that will not be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xubuntu/linux - python3
I am using eclipse-pydev., this is how i debug through eclipse,
i use app.py, inside the project folder(*MyProject)

*app.py*

```
from MyProject import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = {
    'pyramid.reload_templates': 'true',
    'pyramid.debug_authorization': 'false',
    'pyramid.debug_notfound': 'false',
    'pyramid.debug_routematch': 'false',
    'pyramid.default_locale_name': 'en'
    }
    ip="127.0.0.1"
    port="6543"
    app = main(None,settings)

#For waitress
    from waitress import serve
    print("Starting Server on http://{0}:{1}".format(ip,port))    
    serve(app,host=ip,port=port,threads=50)
```

place breakpoints(for example place it in app.py and see the code travel, place it in views.py-return statements and see it gets triggered, when you move to different route) and click on DEBUG Icon in eclipse- debug python app.py., 
eclipse asks for opening debug perspective window and the eclipse-console shows,

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 9380)
```

eclipse open debug perspective window and the breakpoints triggered are shown in the debug window.

I was using,

```
 pserve development.ini
```

but i felt launching web app from eclipse using the above script easy, i can stop running server-localhost using console(eclipse) easily.