# Can't debug a Pyramid project in Eclipse/Pydev with Waitress

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyramid, waitress

I'm trying to setup a working IDE and starting to learn Python with Pyramid framework in a friendly environment like Eclipse/Pydev.

All is working ok (debug, breakpoints included) if I use the old pastescript server by replacing:

```
use = egg:waitress#main --> use = egg:Paste#http
```

in development.ini.

The problem is that the new "way to go" is to use waitress which is supported in Python 3+ versions and pastescript only works on 2.x.

I would want to know if there is any kind of known issue debugging with Waitress and Pydev and if there's any workaround.

These are the errors when I try to debug in Eclipse using Waitress:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Starting server in PID 7508.
Unhandled exception in thread started by serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sh4/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__
    self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeErrorUnhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sh4/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__
: Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sh4/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__
    self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError    self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
: Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sh4/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 200, in __call__
    self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
ThreadedTaskDispatcher object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was already fixed -- please try the latest nightly build to see if it works for you.

See: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on getting it.

Comment: Yep, you were right, i uninstalled the stable version from: http://pydev.org/updates and installed the nightly from: http://pydev.org/nightly and now is working perfect with waitress, thank you.